# I am unable to return an array of a document using an each function in meteor

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, meteor

My html code:

```
<template name="homeItem">
        <li class= "{{selectedClass}}">{{{content}}}</li>
        <li class= "tagsBody">{{#each tags}}<a href="/tagsTemp/{{this}}">{{tags}}</a> {{/each}}</li>
</template>
```

The subscribing to "contents" is being done at the route controller level.
Now the "tags" is an array which is a part of "content" which is a document in a collection named "contentsList".
I have used a homeitem helper function which goes such as this:
JS client code

```
Template.homeItem.helpers({
    'tags':function(){
      return contentsList.findOne({_id: this._id}).tags
    }
});
```

The errors that are returned are:
**1) Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'tags' of undefined.

2)Uncaught Error: {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values.

3)Exception from Tracker recompute function:TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null**
How can I solve this problem? I am new to programming. So, please forgive me for diverting from any programming conventions. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: When you console.log this._id in your tags helpers do you get the right id?

Comment: When I do console.log this._id. It shows an error "cannot read property _id of undefined" but still the "id"s are getting displayed.

Comment: That means that your `this` object doesn't have a property of _id.  Where are you trying to get the _id from?

Comment: I could not understand your question "Where are you trying to get the _id from?".  I am trying to get the id of "content" of "contentsList"

Comment: I have been able to solve the first error: "1) Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'tags' of undefined." Can you give me any suggestion regarding the 2nd and 3rd errors

Answer (score 0):

`contentList.findOne({_id: this._id})` is returning null, so when you try to do `null.tags` it shows up as undefined.

Make sure that a subscription exists for contentsList and that you can search it. Test this by running `contentList.find().fetch()` to see what comes back. If nothing comes back, your subscription doesn't exist.

Comment: contentList.find().fetch() is returning the contents.

Comment: Try `contentsList.findOne({_id: 'yourvarhere'})` and replace 'yourvarhere' with the ID that it wasn't working with. If that works, then your subscription is happening after the template helper is running. You will need to use `waitOn` in iron-router.

Comment: I have been able to solve the first error: "1) Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'tags' of undefined." Can you give me any suggestion regarding the 2nd and 3rd errors.